# How to inherit @IBOutlets from parent ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm desperately trying to understand why the implementation below isn't working.

I'm creating a parent ViewController that is implemented with Interface Builder and has some connected `@IBOutlets`.
When I'm creating a subclass to this ViewController, I get an error at runtime time saying all of my `@IBOutlets` are `nil`.

I tried to "play around" with my `init` methods to see how I can make sure my `@IBOutlets` get initialized but no luck so far.

Anybody would have an idea of how this implementation can be made possible?

```swift
// Super class
class ScenesViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var scenesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topButtonLeft: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var topButtonRight: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var topButtonsStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scenesPageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentNestedStackView: UIStackView!


    // MARK: - Init Method
    convenience init(scenes: [Scene],
                     mainButtonTitle: String,
                     secondaryButtonTitle: String? = nil,
                     topButton: SceneTopButton? = nil,
                     bottomNavLinkTitle: String? = nil,
                     bottomNavLinkColoredText: String? = nil) {

        self.init()

        self.scenes = scenes
        self.mainButtonTitle = mainButtonTitle
        self.secondaryButtonTitle = secondaryButtonTitle
        self.topButton = topButton
        self.bottomNavLinkTitle = bottomNavLinkTitle
        self.bottomNavLinkColoredText = bottomNavLinkColoredText
    }
```

```swift
// Subclass
class OnboardingViewController: ScenesViewController {

    convenience init() {

        self.init() // Not working

        self.scenes = SCENES.ONBOARDING // a constant object
        self.mainButtonTitle = "mainButtonTitle"
        self.secondaryButtonTitle = "secondaryButtonTitle"
        self.topButton = .skip
        self.bottomNavLinkTitle = "bottomNavLinkTitle"
        self.bottomNavLinkColoredText = "Title"
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupButton()
    }
```

The `self.init()` method obviously created a loop so it's a no-go. But can't think of how to properly instantiate the outlets.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should've been `super.init()` when you want to initialize the parent.

Secondly, you can't just simply inherit a layout that was done in storyboards. Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16494461/8314394).

What you could do, is inherit from this viewController, but you would need to connect the IBOutlets manually for each subclass. It means, you will need to go to Storyboards, layout again a view, connect the IBOutlets from the parent view controller, and then the outlets from the subclass (if any).

**UPDATE**:

Select your `OnboardingViewController` and go to Connections Inspector.

[image: XCode connections inspectior]

Drag from the empty circles (like in the image) and connect to the appropriate UI elements of `OnboardingViewController`.

Comment: So I would need to connect the @IBOutlets in `ScenesViewController.xib` to `OnboardingViewController.swift` manually, is that correct?

Comment: I updated my answer. It is vice-versa: connect the @IBOutlets which were inherited from ```ScenesViewController``` to the ```OnboardingViewController.xib``` (if it is done through a nib).

Comment: I send a special thank you to the 'brave' man who just simply down-votes, without any explanation.

Comment: I tried to Upvote but have too few posts so it doesn't appear. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 0):

I did this a different way because I could not understand these posts.  I also needed it for multiple collectionview cells inheriting from one super cell not a VC so maybe that's why (the cells all have the same labels etc but different looks / placement).

But to fix this you need to do the following:

1. Create all the sub cells that will inherit from the super cell just as you normally would.

- Create the xibs
- make it the cell type of the sub cell classes
- drag your IB connections to the sub cell classes just as you normally would
- NOTE: you want all your inherited IBoutlets to be the same name type etc (I copied mine from the other ones and connected to the ones I pasted in)

2. Once all your connections are made to your sub class cells, cut the inherited IBoutlets and paste them into your super cell

- Make all your sub cells inherit and then delete the sub IBOutlets
- That's it your connections are looking at the sub classes and they are seeing the IBoutlet of the super class.

IMO this is easier than trying to figure out how to connect to the super class

Comment: It would be better to post this on the other question and flag this question as a duplicate. That's always better than posting the same answer on two questions.